# wrong margin size after transforms?

Tags: css, html, transform, css-transforms

I am confused by the size of the margins in this example on chrome (v 56.0.2924.87 as of posting)

```
<div class='a'><div class='b'></div></div>
```

Here is the simple css:

```
.a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.b {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;

  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform: scale( 0.25 );

  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/EZRZbx?editors=1100

Some questions:

- Why is the top margin different from the bottom margin?  The top margin takes up 20px while the bottom just a few pixels.
- Why isn't the top margin scaled?  I expected the margin value of 20px to be scaled just like the content.
- What value would I used for the bottom margin to make it the same as the top margin?

Comment: `.a` should be `position:relative`. There is nothing wrong with Chrome nor margin. Look into your `transform: matrix(0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0);` It seems to causing this weird behaviour.

Comment: `.a {position:relative}` does not change rendering.  `transform: scale( 0.25 )` also does not change rendering. Both changes still result in a 20px top margin and a smaller bottom margin. Obviously my problem involves a transform :-D  That's what I am trying to understand.   http://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/KaeKJY?editors=1100

Comment: Perhaps writing every transform value separately, for ex. `transform:skew();` `transform:rotateX();`, would help understand what your matrix does. Compiled matrix can be just about anything.